# How to add pages a part of theme in Orchard CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I need to add a CSHTML/HtML both type of pages as the part of the theme only (i.e. inside the theme folder) They are added in the folder but we can use only one page of the theme i.e. Layout.cshtml as master page. The other I need to add are test pages but I need to use that as to put some content & display. How to display them?

```
http://localhost:65012/Themes/MyTheme/demos/layout1.html
```

This gives 'The resource cannot be found' Error.
any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

To be able to download static files you need a to enable the [StaticFileModule](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview) of II7, or the StaticFileHandler for II6.

The fastest way to do so is copy the *web.config* file from a folder like [*Media*](https://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Orchard.Web/Media/web.config) to your *demos* folder.